# Custom Sort Order in Pandas with Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with multiindex, where level 0 is the following:

```
['-67', '67', '-68', '68']
```

when importing the data through a java interface, the data loads in this order:

```
['-67', '-68', '67', '68']
```

I plan on appending the timestamps from each level 0 index, so having them in the correct order is important. The correct order is:

`['-##', '##', .....]` for as many level 0 datasets are being analyzed.

This also needs to be a generic solution, as it will involve many datasets.

I've looked at the solutions for custom sorting, but nothing provided a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `sorted` with `key` and `lambda`

```
sorted(['-67', '-68', '67', '68'],key= lambda x : abs(int(x)))
Out[882]: ['-67', '67', '-68', '68']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure, that the negative number appears before the positive one, you can do the following:

```
sorted(list_name, key = lambda x : (abs(int(x), int(x) > 0)))
```